# Is there a way to run a hybrid app (phonegap cordova) on a windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows, mobile, cordova

I can obviously run a Android VM and run it.. but I am basically trying to skin the "can a Winwows 8 app run on windows 7" cat a different way. My app is Hybrid - so no OS specific dependencies. My customers have a weird requirement where their companies are not ready to go to Windows 8 yet, but we want to be able to give them a hybrid app that was developed for Android, iOS and (eventually Win8) that will function on a Windows 7 machine. The app itself is very "mouse usable".

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the [Ripple emulator](http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/). A [beta version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en) is available for Google Chrome in the Chrome Web Store, though it's a bit out-of-date with respect to the latest versions of Phonegap. Otherwise, for phonegap 3.x, you can [install it using npm](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-ripple.git;a=blob_plain;f=README.md;hb=HEAD).